# Is an MVC Async controller that calls WebResponse still async?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library

We have a large library that makes a lot of HTTP calls using HttpWebRequest to get data.  Rewriting this library to make use of async calls with the HTTPClient would be a bear.  So, I was wondering if I could create async controllers that use a taskfactory to call into our library and whether the calls that are ultimately made via the WebClient would be asynch or they would still be synch.  Are there any problems/side-effects I might cause by trying to mix  async with the old HttpWebRequest?

Comment: `WebClient` is not new, it has been there at least since .Net 1.1. Do you mean `HtppClient`, that's new in .Net 4.5 and ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion.  You are right, I meant the new HttpClient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're proposing the answer is: no, changing the services the client talks to to be async would not help. The client would still block a CPU thread while the I/O is outstanding with the server, whether the server is async or not.

There's no reason to switch away from `HttpWebRequest`. You can use [`TaskFactory::FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) in .NET 4.0 to call `HttpWebRequest::BeginGetResponse`. That looks something like this:

```
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

Task<WebResponse> getResponseTask = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                                                myWebRequest.BeginGetResponse,
                                                myWebRequest.EndGetResponse,
                                                null);

getResponseTask.ContinueWith(getResponseAntecedent =>
{
   WebResponse webResponse = getResponseAntecedent.Result;

   Stream webResponseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

   // read from stream async too... eventually dispose of it
});
```

In .NET 4.5 you can *still* continue to use `HttpWebRequest` and use the new [`GetResponseAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with the new `await` features in C# to make life a heck of a lot easier:

```
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

using(WebResponse webResponse = await myWebRequest.GetResponseAsync())
using(Stream webResponseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
     // read from stream async, etc.
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot.  I figured that the call would still block and it never occurred to me that WebRequest may have been extended to support async, but sure enough, browsing through the methods shows me your answer.  Thanks!